# Regarding Sweden residence permit (UT card) renewal

Tags: sweden

I am an Indian national. I have a Swedish permanent work and residence permit (UT Card). The validity of my UT card is going to expire soon. I don't have a permanent job at present in Sweden. I am in India currently and will be travelling to Sweden before my UT card expires. Please let me know how and where to apply for the UT card extension and what are the documents that I need while applying for the extension.

Comment: When you apply for an extension of your work permit, you will need to demonstrate that the conditions of the work permit have been met during the entire time you have held a work permit in Sweden. You must also show that you have been offered a job that meets the conditions of your work permit. https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Working-in-Sweden/Employed/If-you-are-in-Sweden/Extending-a-permit.html